# Search and replace null and dot in a column of file

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I want to search and replace null and dot in a column of file using `awk` or `sed`.

The file's content is:

```
02-01-12 28.46
02-02-12 27.15
02-03-12 
02-04-12 27.36
02-05-12 47.57
02-06-12 27.01
02-07-12 27.41
02-08-12 27.27
02-09-12 27.39
02-10-12 .
02-11-12 27.44
02-12-12 49.93
02-13-12 26.99
02-14-12 27.47
02-15-12 27.21
02-16-12 27.48
02-17-12 27.66
02-18-12 27.15
02-19-12 51.74
02-20-12 27.37
```

The dots and null value can be be appeared in any rows in the file, I want to replace null and dots with the value above, say ,

```
02-01-12 28.46
02-02-12 27.15
02-03-12 27.15     ****** replace with the above value
02-04-12 27.36
02-05-12 47.57
02-06-12 27.01
02-07-12 27.41
02-08-12 27.27
02-09-12 27.39
02-10-12 27.39     ****** replace with the above value
02-11-12 27.44
02-12-12 49.93
02-13-12 26.99
02-14-12 27.47
02-15-12 27.21
02-16-12 27.48
02-17-12 27.66
02-18-12 27.15
02-19-12 51.74
02-20-12 27.37
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -i '$!N;s/^\(.\{9\}\(.*\)\n.\{9\}\)\.\?$/\1\2/;P;D' file
```

Comment: Wow. My command is three times longer. I'm not going to post it now :) You are not even using the hold space! That's just blowing my mind. P.S. Although you're cheating with this `.{9}` stuff. That looks a little dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN {prev = "00.00"} NF < 2 || $2 == "." {$2 = prev} {prev = $2; print}' filename
```

If you have multiple columns which might have missing data:

```
awk 'BEGIN {p = "00.00"} {for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {if (! $i || $i == ".") {if (prev[i]) {$i = prev[i]} else {$i = p}}; prev[i] = $i}; print}' filename
```

Comment: How about I have a file have 4 columns , say 1st column is date , another 3 columns are numbers

Comment: @IvanChan: This should still work if column 2 is the only one with missing values. If there might be missing values in the other columns as well, you should have specified your problem more completely in the question. A similar technique could be used. You would just need to iterate over the fields and `prev` would need to be an array indexed by the field number. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following awk script should work:

```
BEGIN {
    last="00.00"
}

{
    if ($2 != "" && $2 != ".") {
        last=$2
    }
    print $1 " " last
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v prev=00.00 'NF<2 || $2=="." { print $1, prev; next }{prev=$2}1' input-file
```

Comment: How about I have a file have 4 columns , say 1st column is date , another 3 columns are numbers

Comment: For multiple columns, it is difficult to replace a blank field using awk, since awk will not be able to easily distinguish a line that has 4 fields 2 of which are blank and a line with just 2 fields, so I'll assume you are only replacing fields of ".".  `awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if( $i == "." )$i=p[i] else p[i]=$i}1'`